# problem with subdomain after redirection nameserver

Tags: subdomain

I have redirect my domain from one server to another.And my website has sub domain concept.Before redirection this was running well but when this redirected (nameserver) to another server my subdomain is not opening.But another which related with "www" is opening well.I am getting an error

" Network - DNS Lookup Error
The address delh.mydomain.com cannot be found."

What is shoud to do.
I have written my htaccess code is like

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /subdomain/$1 [L]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`delh.sliceindia.com` does not appear to exist, as far as the DNS system is concerned. Have you properly configured the `sliceindia.com` zone to have an `A` record for the `delh` host? Or a wildcard on the parent `sliceindia.com`? Either you haven't, or it's not propagated yet. Either way, the redirect can't work if there's no HTTP hits coming into the server.